# How does the WordPress URL Routing work?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, routes

I would like to try and mimic how WordPress has their URL routing system designed, only a much more simplistic level. Can someone help me understand how they have their routing system designed so that I could try and mimic it for my own development.

I see that their routing is set up like this:

```
    Array
(
    [sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml$] => index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$matches[2]
    [sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml\.gz$] => index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$matches[2];zip=true
    [sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.html$] => index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$matches[2];html=true
    [sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.html.gz$] => index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$matches[2];html=true;zip=true
    [category/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [category/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [category/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [category/(.+?)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]
    [tag/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [tag/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [tag/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [tag/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]
    [type/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [type/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [type/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [type/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]
    [robots\.txt$] => index.php?robots=1
    [.*wp-(atom|rdf|rss|rss2|feed|commentsrss2)\.php$] => index.php?feed=old
    [.*wp-app\.php(/.*)?$] => index.php?error=403
    [.*wp-register.php$] => index.php?register=true
    [feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]
    [(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]
    [page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?&paged=$matches[1]
    [comments/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]&withcomments=1
    [comments/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]&withcomments=1
    [search/(.+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [search/(.+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [search/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [search/(.+)/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]
    [author/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [author/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [author/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [author/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&tb=1
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&cpage=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&page=$matches[4]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&cpage=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [(.?.+?)/trackback/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [(.?.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [(.?.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [(.?.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [(.?.+?)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
)
```

From there, I am having a tough time following how they physically route all of the traffic through the single index.php file. Conceptually, I understand the commands in the array that setup the URL rewrites and how the .htaccess file works, but I just can't seem to understand how it physically executes the code to pass the parameters through the index.php files.

Anyone have any good tutorials or examples?

Comment: You'll probably get better answers over on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Install wordpress, then check your .htaccess file and the index.php file. Suggesting tutorials or external learning resources if off-topic for StackOverflow. Going in great detail how Wordpress does things is too broad for the Q&A format. You already know the buzz-word for it (routing) and already know an example of where it is used. Go forth. Use google. There is no real answer we can give here.